# Grayscale Background Changing Text Color? CSS

Tags: html, css

My goal is to have a background image span the entire screen like this: http://playjudgey.com/

I am trying to change my background image to be grayscale, but every time I do, it changes all of the text that is written over the image. I assume that the filter is applying to everything that is inside of the my div. My code is below:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="hometext">
                You are the best!
            </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

So this is what I did for my CSS:

```
.hometext {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;

}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: url('../img/money.jpg');
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(1);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The issue is that the text I write is not red, but gray. Is there any way to code this differently so my text will appear colored? Or should I just turn the image grayscale through an outside program?

Comment: I've solved similar issues with opacity causing the text to fade.  You can put the hometext div outside of the wrapper and make them both absolute.  See my answer and fiddle below.

Answer (score 4):

You can get this same effect with a blend mode, that applies only to the background, and besides, it has more support (FF)

```css
.hometext {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
  font-size: 60px;

}

.wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-image: url('http://placekitten.com/1000/750');
    background-color: gray;
    background-blend-mode: luminosity;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
    <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="hometext">
                You are the best!
            </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no need to change the background color dynamically, I would just change it to grayscale in a basic image editor. CSS `filter` is not fully cross-browser compatible I believe anyways, so you will be safer that way (and easier).

If you were to keep things how they are now, though, you would just need to change the `filter` property on your text as its inheriting it from your parent `div`.

Answer (score 0):

What if you put your hometext div outside of the wrapper, making them both absolute:

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper"></div>
<div class="hometext">
          You are the best!
</div>
```

```
.hometext {
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Additional CSS will be needed for styling and position, but here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lepe84tu/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting the background image on `.wrapper`, you could make another `div` as a sibling of `.hometext` that has the image as the background - that way you can style the image and the text independently.

Answer (score -2):

Your `<div class="wrapper">` div is wrapping also your `hometext` div. You should try this:

```
.hometext {
    width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    color: red !important;
    text-align: center;

}
```

Comment: I don't think `!important` should be used in this case nor do I think that would even solve the problem. Its an inheritance problem with `filter` being inherited from the wrapper to the child text.